# Appending JSON file: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, walmart-api

In short, for a Data Science class, I'm running a loop (Python 3) on Walmart to query item information and build a comprehensive data set saved in JSON. (In this case laptops in category electronics within the walmart api.)

The issue:
--I can read the first set of 25 items
--When I append, items 26 +, create the type error

Here is my append code

```
    a = []
    if not os.path.isfile('filename.json'):
        a.append(entry['items'])
        with open('filename.json', mode='w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(entry['items'], indent=4))
    else:
        with open('filename.json') as feedsjson:
            feeds = json.load(feedsjson)

        feeds.append(entry['items'])
        with open('filename.json', mode='w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(feeds, indent=4))
```

[Here is the json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18bPipyfTfqse-EcmkAhm-ke2dVq_s_ND/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the print code.  Works on items 1-25 only

```
filepath = os.path.join('filename.json')   
with open(filepath) as jsonfile:
    json_data = json.load(jsonfile)

    for i in range(len(json_data)):
        itemId = json_data[i]['itemId']
        print(itemId)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your json data, you have a list on 26th item. So you can't look for a key on a list.

In other words, `itemId` is not an index for a list.